# How do I shrink root partition?

Tags: partitioning, root

I am in a sorta big trouble.

I ran into problems with Win8 and after fading up about it I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I was so frustrated I replaced Windows 8 and made a huge root directory of 9XX GB. 
Please tell me how can I make three partitions of 250gigs so that I can install Windows 7 in one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a tool that can shrink current schema to use available free speace

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky (can lead to data loss).  Consider backing up any important data and starting fresh (delete Ubuntu and reinstall).  If you're still reading, these are the basic steps:

1. Boot into a live session (Ubuntu live cd)
2. Unmount and perform a filesystem check that resides on the partition you want to reduce
3. Reduce the size of the filesystem with the resize2fs command
4. Delete the partition's entry in the partition table with the fdisk command (or similar)
5. Create a new, and smaller (exactly the same size as in step #3), partition entry in the partition table with fdisk (or similar)
6. Mount the filesystem

When installing Windows, you will see free space.  Tell it to use 250GB of it.